# SQL Server Analysis Services is hanging every day

Tags: sql-server, ssas

On one of my SQL Servers, `Analysis Services` is hanging every day and daily cubes are not processing. If I try to restart the `Analysis Services`, the services are going to stopping state. I am doing forceful reboot of server to run the cubes.

A few blogs mentioned this might be a service pack issue so I upgraded to `SP3 + CU4`, but I am still getting the error.

While running the cubes through SQL Agent Jobs, I am getting following error:

> Error ErrorCode="3238133760" Description="File system error: The
>   following error occurred during a file operation: .
>   (\?\L:\Olap\Data\MYCube.0.db\ MYC.0.dim\18.Fact ID Key.MHS)."

After this, I am rebooting the server and rerunning the jobs without any issue.

What could be causing this?  How do I debug this?

Comment: Even i ran the CHKDSK  against the drive L, 0 KB in bad sector.                                                   Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.
No further action is required.

Comment: Are you running out of space?

Comment: no, disk has sufficient free space

Comment: Even while the build is running? Have you monitored the free space during the cube build?

Comment: yes, it has 140 GB free space during the cube build